# Many to many relationship model on Django

Tags: django

I have two tables called User and Courses and I want to show the relationship between them my implementing a many-to-many relationship model. I want to implement 3 model classes in total as so:

```
# user/model.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_newbie = models.BooleanField(default=False)



#courses/model.py

from django.db import models
from register.models import User

class Courses(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = False)

class StatusHasCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How do I implement this so only the relationship between `User` that have `is_status = True` are only accessed in the `StatusHasCourse` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to specify how to limit the choices. So in this specific case, we can make use of a [**`Q`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) that specifies `is_status=True`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class StatusHasCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to=Q(is_status=True)
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```